# Camel replaceFromWith and Mock a JMS destination - Spring Boot

Tags: apache-camel

I've checked the Camel In Action 2 Chapter-9 examples, and looked at this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29581561/in-an-apache-camel-application-how-can-unit-tests-inject-mock-endpoints-in-plac) and [this user-group thread](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/camel-spring-boot-UseAdviceWith-td5780949.html), but still stuck...

I am using Spring-boot and Camel 2.18.x
I am trying to combine the two [examples from Camel sample code](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-spring-boot/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/spring/boot/mockendpoints), into one: to mockEndpoint and also replaceFrom

**Working scenario:**

1. I create a test route direct-->seda
2. I use Advicewith, and mock all endpoints
3. My test works fine

**Working scenario:**

1. I changed the destination, to have direct-->jms
2. I get an exception at the last, and see JMS failing to create a session.

**Expectation:** I assume that JMS would be replaced by the mock, and the logs seem to indicate so. Not sure why the JMSProducer is being invoked anyway. Is this expected behavior?

**Sample Route:**

```
    from("direct:start")
            .id("testroute")
            .log("${body}")
            //.to("seda:finish")   //This works okay
            .to("jms:XYZ_Q")
     ;
```

**Unit-test class:**

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@MockEndpoints
@UseAdviceWith
@SpringBootTest(classes = {UnitTestApplication.class, SampleTest.class})
public class SampleTest {

    @Autowired
    private CamelContext camelContext;

    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @Test
    public void test01() throws Exception {
        RouteDefinition route = camelContext.getRouteDefinition("testroute");
        AdviceWithRouteBuilder adviceWithRB = new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                replaceFromWith("direct:renamed");
            }
        };

        route.adviceWith(camelContext, adviceWithRB);
        camelContext.start();

        producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:renamed", "  8888888820130601");
    }
}
```

I expected that the JMS component would not attempt to do anything, but would be replaced by the mock. Is this an incorrect understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume that JMS would be replaced by the mock

1. Nope, it won't be replaced, because `replaceFromWith(..)` replaces the route's input (`from(..)`) with a new endpoint URI. It should work in the following case (used your example):

   ```
   from("jms:XYZ_Q")
       .id("testroute")
       .log("${body}");
       //.to("seda:finish")   //This works okay
       //.to("jms:XYZ_Q")
   ```
2. If you would like to mock the `.to("jms:XYZ_Q")` part (from your question) then you can use the `weaveByIdToString()`, `weaveById()`, etc functions. More info: http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html#AdviceWith-UsingAdviceWithRouteBuilder